# Transaction Date in Extended Report

Tags: civireport

Using the "Bookkeeping with extra fields" template, I noticed I was occasionally missing some transactions whenever I filtered on Transaction Date. I believe the issue is caused by the filter using only the date and not the time.

For example, if today is February 10 and I filter Transaction Date on "Yesterday", the WHERE clause looks like:

> ( financial_trxn.trxn_date >= '20190209') AND ( financial_trxn.trxn_date <= '20190209' )

Any transaction that isn't exactly at midnight is lost. Comparing to the Date Received filter, it uses date and time:

> ( contribution.receive_date >= '20190209000000') AND ( contribution.receive_date <= '20190209235959' )

Perhaps I'm misinterpreting the use of the filters. I can run the same query directly, but with the time included for Transaction Date, and it seems to return the correct results.

- CiviCRM 5.10.0
- PHP 7.2.13
- MySQL 5.7.23
- Wordpress 5.0.3

EDIT - originally this Q referenced ExtendedReports 3.5 but turns out it was a core report

Comment: Suggest you open an issue at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport if you are pretty certain about your findings

Comment: I just realized that the issue exists in the standard Bookkeeping Transactions report. I'm so used to using Eileen's extended version that I had forgotten the standard report.

Comment: in that case are you able to replicate it at dmaster.demo.civicrm.org?

Comment: Yes, same behavior on dmaster and wpmaster.

Comment: Can you pls update the question and ideally create an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been reported in https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/report/issues/7.